# Can we allow "pass-through" for a CSS style from a parent to its decendants?

Tags: css

For example, if we need to set a `div`'s `font-size` to `22px`, is there a possible way to let the descendants of this `div` still inherit from the `font-size` from `body`? (or any inheritable style, thanks to @Sourabh for pointing out `background` is not inherited).

I think a key point is that so that we can change the style of `body` or some parent and let it pass through, even though there is an intermediate change of style.  So preferably, we won't do it by:

```css
body, #foo * { font-size: 16px }
#foo { font-size: 22px }
```

This is related to the case as described in [How to solve flicker on iPad when event delegation is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173723/how-to-solve-flicker-on-ipad-when-event-delegation-is-used) , where the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` need to be set for a `div`, but the descendants of this `div` will be best to inherit what is above this `div` (the parent of this `div`).

I can use JavaScript to put the style of this `div` in a temporary variable, and then change the `div`'s style, and then change the style for just the immediately children of this `div` to the value of that temporary variable, but then whatever that is set for the style of `body` won't get inherited by those children or their descendants.

Comment: Do the descendants actually have to be descendants? Do you have enough control of the structure to use another `<div`> that sits "to the side" in the DOM hierarchy, but is positioned to be where it currently is?

Comment: yes I think those have to be descendants -- that's how event delegation works: we bind the "click" handler on the `div`, and get the item clicked on by `ev.target`, instead of binding 1000 event handlers to 1000 elements (or any number N)

Answer (score 1):

No. In the DOM, a descendant element will inherit any inheritable CSS of the parent(s). You can 'reset' it back to match the parent item by declaring it again, but you can't do exactly what you are asking which is only changing the BODY style declaration.

Off the top of my head, the one solution I can think of would be not rely on pure inheritance from the `body` element but instead create a class and use it on all elements where you want to control aspects from one declaration. That still may be tricky due to CSS specificity, though.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could use a > combinator like so:

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/xnWYa/)

```
body, #foo { background: yellow }
#foo>* { background: blue }
```

or like so:

[Working Example2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/xnWYa/1/)

```
body {
    background: yellow;
}
#foo {
    background: blue;
}
#foo>* {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: no, the desired effect is that we don't have to specify the style for the children but just let the children (and their descendants) get that style from above `foo`

Comment: @動靜能量 I doubt that you can do that in css alone see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277256/cancel-a-css-declaration

Answer (score 0):

**W3C `background-color` Stats**

> **Initial:  transparent**
>
> **Inherited:  no**

All elements are transparent regardless of their parent's `background-color`. But that color is `transparent` so parent's color is visible on the child. So basically, if you want them to inherit color, **you can't** (not with CSS at least) (there might be a trick that I am not aware of). You have to specify the color for every element if you don't want it to be `transparent`.

Comment: oh so maybe I made a bad example, I will correct this in my question to say `font-size` instead

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *not quite*.

You *can* reset a property to its initial values by using the `initial` css keyword, which is particularly useful for these user-agent set styles (like `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`)

[See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCfqy/).

Note however that this isn't the value that would be set by default if the parent didn't exist, but literally the browser's default setting. In particular, `body` level formatting is *not* taken into account.

---

I've also included the `default` keyword, which is effectively the same as not including any font-size specifier at all - it goes up the cascade chain to find one that has a font-size specified, in this case on the element-name selector.